# Is it ok to use the universal selector in bootstrap 3.1?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working a lot with `position absolute` and i don't want to set position relative on the parent of each DOM element every single time. To skip that i use

```
body *{
    position:relative;
}
```

but i don't know if this is a good idea or if it will break something in bootstrap.

can anyone help me on this? or tell me if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: why not just apply it to the div only?

Comment: why are you using `position: absolute` so much is the real question.  Bootstrap has a great grid system, you most likely would be much better off learning how to use it.  And yes - doing this will make many things in bootstrap now work correctly.

Comment: It is due to the amount of videos i have on the webapp it is not about how to use the  grid system. i have to set text on videos but bootstrap doesn't provide that so i have to do it on my one that is why i am asking if someone had the same problem before

Comment: Indeed, continuing what @dave said, see this related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23009288/is-there-anything-wrong-with-positioning-all-elements-relatively The question is almost never about the use of the universal selector, but what sort of styles you're applying to every element, and in the *vast majority* of cases you should never set a different default from what is already decided by the browser or the standard.

Comment: What if you want the reference to be an element that is not the immediate parent? You couldn't get that to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the universal selector, but I suggest you not to use it(*). Instead use selector in more appropriate way like:

```
.relative {
  position: relative;
}
```

And, give the parent element `class="relative"`.

This way, you can position only the required elements, and it may increase web-page performance.

Comment: That class is not very semantic. It would be better if the OP created a class like `.positioning-reference{position:relative}`